# How to derive this equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

> [image]

How to derive this equation? It comes from a book named Seismic Wave Propagation in Stratified Media.

Comment: Hint: Multiply by a volume element $\delta v$ and you have Newton's second law.

Comment: Could you explain the detail about how it is derived or tell me  where I can reference？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two forces in presence and, because the system is in equilibrium (=0), the *change* in one will be compensated by a *change* in the other.
A *change* in this context is decoded to 'the rate of change in relation to space: $\frac{d}{dx_i}$ '
$\frac{d\sigma}{dx_i}$ is a force per unit length and
$\frac{d\psi}{dx_i}$ is an acceleration  per unit length, times mass ($\rho_0$) is also a force per unit length (recall Newton f=m.a) and thus they can be added or subtracted.